# Windows azure insert,query,delete and update on mobile service

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using windows azure mobile services. From the portal, I create a mobile service with an sql database.
I have successfully inserted data into the table.
But I can not read data from the sql database or update or delete.
I am pretty new in this platform. 
A broad description or a sample project file or better a video tutorial of insert,update,delete,query on azure mobile service is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the current portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com/):

When you create a new Azure Mobile Service, on the Quick Start page (the icon that looks like a cloud with a lightning bolt through it), you should be able to see multiple platform starter applications including Windows, iOS, Android, JavaScript, etc.

If you are using the preview portal (http://portal.azure.com)

Once your mobile app is created, you can open the Mobile App blade, and click the "Add Client" icon at the top to open the "Quick Start" blade to download a sample working client.

Each of these started applications will give you a code example for Create, Read, Update and Delete methods in your application. You can always look at the Azure documentation for more detailed walkthroughs of applications including authentication, offline data and notifications.

Finally, if that is enough to get you going, you can check out this page which shows how to call the different methods for doing Read, Update and Delete.

Updated link (may need to click a platform selection once the page loads):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/

Comment: sir, I admire your comment. can u please give me a sample project file related to insert, update, delete, query on a table. I am trying two days ... nothing happens ...

Comment: The quickstart IS a sample project for Insert, Update, Delete, etc. The way to use Mobile Services is to run a client project on Windows, iOS, Android, etc.

Comment: Here are some videos:

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Windows-Store-app-Creating-your-first-app-using-the-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services-Quickstart

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Introduction-to-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/NET-Backend-on-Azure-Mobile-Services-with-Donna-Malayeri